# Android kotlin method accept any object type as parameter

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to pass 2 different object types to a method to update the view. How can I have this method 
accept 2 different object types and access them instead of having 2 different methods for 2 different object types.

I needed something like this -

```
fun updateView(object: Any<T>) {
   //Access the objects here to update the view
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you need just two functions. Perhaps you can share some internal logic with a thirds function which takes in some data that they do actually share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun <T : Any> updateView(obj: T) {
    //Access the objects here to update the view
}
```

OR

```
fun updateView(obj: Any ?= null, obj2:Any ?= null) {
    // Access the objects here to update the view

    // pass check nullity and use which you want (or not null), other parameter will remain null

    obj?.let {
       it...
    }

    obj2?.let {
       it...
    }
}
```

Call

```
updateView(obj1, obj2)

// OR

updateView(obj2 = myObj2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use interfaces for this:

```
interface ViewInterface {
    fun action() 
}

class ObjectA : ViewInterface {...}
class ObjectB : ViewInterface {...}

fun updateView(ob: ViewInterface) {
    ob.action()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try something like this

```
fun updateView(variable1: Any? = null, variable2:Any? = null) {
//Access the objects here to update the view
}
```

using named parameters, you can then just set the variables you need when calling the method:

```
 updateView(variable1 = "something")
 updateView(variable2 = "something else")
```

Comment: Yeah but the method is called from two different places. So variable1 has to be null once and next time variable2 has to be null. Both are never available at the same time

Comment: @Maria then you should include that in your question :D i'll update now

Answer (score 1):

Have your 2 objects implement the same interface or inherit from the same superclass then do something like:

```
fun updateView(object: MyInterface) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: No they dont implement same interface nor they inherit from same superclass

Comment: Please check my other answer

Answer (score 1):

You can pass two types of object by this way

```
 fun updateView(data:Any? = null,data2:Any?=null) {
    //Cast Your Object To your desired type and also can pass null too
    // Access the objects here to update the view
}
```

Comment: Yeah but the method is called from two different places. So variable1 has to be null once and next time variable2 has to be null. Both are never available at the same time

Comment: @maria do Mention in Question this, Updated Answere

Answer (score 1):

Use polymorphism

```
fun updateView(object: X) {
    ...
}

fun updateView(object: Y) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: she wrote

"instead of having 2 different methods for 2 different object types"


Also Kotlin has default values in function parameters instead of duplicating methods

Comment: Yeah makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I would advise separating the two functions, or to use inheritance of some sort to use a single function. But as I see none of those above (which are correct, from the SOLID point of view) satisfies your request, you can just check inside the function based on class.

```
fun updateView(object: Any) {

when(object){
    is Class1Type -> // do whatever fits for the first case
    is Class2Type -> // do whatever fits for the second case
    else -> // etc.
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is not related to Kotlin at all. Just make both of them implement an interface and use this interface as the function parameter type.
In general, accepting `Any` as an input type is not a good practice and using generics is an overkill.

```
interface DoesStuff

class DoesStuffA: DoesStuff { }

class DoesStuffB: DoesStuff { }

fun doStuff(doer: DoesStuff) {
    // do stuff

    // if need to distinguish between types
    when (doer) {
        is DoesStuffA -> // do A
        is DoesStuffB -> // do B
    }
}
```